# People Picker adaptive element in adaptive cards doesn't work in Teams Android app

Tags: android, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I'm trying to use the People Picker element in my adaptive cards and it works very well on the Desktop and iPhone version of Teams. Teams for Android just shows "Unable to show options right now" error message.

Anything I'm missing or is this a bug on the Microsoft side?

[image: People picker on Teams for Android]

For full disclosure this is the JSON being fed to Teams:

```
{
  "task": {
    "value": {
      "card": {
        "content": {
          "type": "AdaptiveCard",
          "body": [
            {
              "isMultiline": false,
              "maxLength": 0,
              "style": null,
              "value": "10",
              "isRequired": false,
              "id": "xxxId",
              "separator": false,
              "isVisible": false,
              "type": "Input.Text"
            },
            {
              "columns": [
                {
                  "width": "100px",
                  "items": [
                    {
                      "horizontalAlignment": null,
                      "selectAction": {
                        "data": {
                          "formAction": "showXXX"
                        },
                        "type": "Action.Submit"
                      },
                      "size": "large",
                      "style": null,
                      "url": "https://us-prod.asyncgw.teams.microsoft.com/urlp/v1/url/content?url=https%3a%2f%2fmedia.xxx.com%2fapp%2fimages%2fxxx%2fsmall%2fyyy.png",
                      "height": "auto",
                      "separator": false,
                      "type": "Image"
                    }
                  ],
                  "verticalContentAlignment": "center",
                  "separator": false,
                  "type": "Column"
                },
                {
                  "width": "200px",
                  "items": [
                    {
                      "color": null,
                      "horizontalAlignment": null,
                      "isSubtle": false,
                      "maxLines": 0,
                      "size": null,
                      "text": "ZZZ",
                      "weight": null,
                      "wrap": true,
                      "separator": false,
                      "type": "TextBlock"
                    },
                    {
                      "actions": [
                        {
                          "data": {
                            "formAction": "showXXX"
                          },
                          "title": "change",
                          "type": "Action.Submit"
                        }
                      ],
                      "separator": false,
                      "type": "ActionSet"
                    }
                  ],
                  "verticalContentAlignment": "center",
                  "separator": false,
                  "type": "Column"
                }
              ],
              "spacing": "extraLarge",
              "separator": true,
              "type": "ColumnSet"
            },
            {
              "choices": [],
              "isMultiSelect": true,
              "style": "filtered",
              "value": "",
              "wrap": true,
              "choices.data": {
                "type": "Data.Query",
                "dataset": "graph.microsoft.com/users?scope=currentContext"
              },
              "isRequired": false,
              "label": "Search Recipients",
              "id": "recipientIds",
              "separator": false,
              "type": "Input.ChoiceSet"
            },
            {
              "isMultiline": true,
              "maxLength": 125,
              "style": null,
              "value": "",
              "isRequired": false,
              "errorMessage": "Enter a recipient message",
              "label": "Message for recipient(s):",
              "id": "message",
              "spacing": "large",
              "separator": true,
              "type": "Input.Text"
            }
          ],
          "actions": [
            {
              "data": {
                "formAction": "finalSubmit"
              },
              "title": "Send",
              "style": "positive",
              "type": "Action.Submit"
            }
          ],
          "version": "1.0"
        },
        "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive"
      },
      "width": 550
    },
    "type": "continue"
  },
  "responseType": "task"
}
```

Comment: Could you please refer below sample
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-people-picker-adaptive-card/csharp

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT I just deployed the sample. Exactly the same issue as with my code. Android version is broken.

Comment: We have tested this sample. We are able to repro this issue and we have raised a bug for it.

We will let you know once we get updates on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug in Teams. For now, we have been granted an exception for the Teams app review process.

Comment: This bug has fixed now. Could you please update the Teams version and check again.

Comment: I confirm it's all good now. Thanks.